# PHP: Constant name from a variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP class that looks like this

```
class Painter {
    const COLOR_PHYSIC = 'brown';
    const COLOR_PSYCHIC = 'purple';
    const COLOR_ATTACKER = 'dodgerblue';
    const COLOR_DEFENDER = 'darkorange';

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        if(defined('self::'.$name)) $name = self::$$name;

        return '<span class="'.$name.'">'.$arguments[0].'</span>';
    }
}
```

Which returns a colored html representation of a string. Example usage:

```
$painter->red('Text'); // <span class="red">Text</span>
```

I would also like to have some preset colors that could be changed in future, if such necessity is present, which is where I am stuck.

if I run this line

```
$painter->COLOR_DEFENDER('Text');
```

I get the error message

> Access to undeclared static property: Painter::$COLOR_DEFENDER

How can I modify the code so that `$name` can be as well interpreted as a constant?

Also on a side note, I am curious to find out, if I were to change the method of storing preset colors to an array instead of constants, would that use less memory? I'd be really happy if someone more familiar with under-the-hood PHP can answer this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What’s the matter with declaring private members instead of constants?

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't actually know why I decided to go with constants, but anyhow it's still a valid question which I'd love to know the answer to

Comment: You are using 2 $ signes in `self::$name`. Can you remove 1 and try it again.

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you really want to use some php-magic just to hide a second function parameter? Why not simply `->colorize($text, $color)`? Like in this [demo](http://3v4l.org/VAI1q). Nice clean api, no fancy hard to explain stuff.

Comment: @RonakPatel the double $$ is used to parse the value of $name as a variable to `self::` - Hense why the error is: `Access to undeclared static property:` because it's an undeclared property.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Then you’d likely go with http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php

Comment: @Yoshi I guess that is just a style of coding. I hate to have repeating stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (defined('self::' . $name)) {
    $name = constant('self::' . $name);
}
```

To dynamically retrieve constants, you need to use the [`constant` function](http://php.net/constant).

Comment: +1 - I didn't realise this worked within classes but then it couples with `defined()`

Comment: @Ash Even if it didn't: `constant(__CLASS__ . '::' . $name)`... ;)

Comment: Valid point - constants are publicly accessible there isn't any reason for that not to work.